# How to change the value of a variable while debugging Visual C++ progrmme-VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, out-of-memory, visual-studio-debugging

My programme contains a large array of 600000 elements (each element is a structure). when I was debugging the programme, it was given OutOfMemoryException at

```
FlightLeg *legRecord= new  FlightLeg[600000];(FlightLeg is a structure)
```

The programme consumes lot of time since it has to do several data processings and initial data loadings (more than two days!).

So I want to do changes while debugging. I think changing 600000 to some smaller value will help. If I'm wrong please give me any suggestions.

Could you tell me is there a way to change 600000 while debugging? Because I don't want to lose the previous data loadings which consumed two days.

Comment: Why are you using a pointer to a fixed size array to begin with? I'm not completely clear on the nature of your application, however if possible I do suggest you use a vector<FlightLeg>, and push_back a new FlightLeg when a new one is needed.

Comment: Look up "Edit And Continue".

Comment: @ librik. thanks for your comment. I'm using manged code. so Edit And Continue does not work for me.

Comment: @johnathon.thank you.yes now i have to stop my programme and try out vector.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on few things:

- The `sizeof` the structure `FlightLeg`. If one `FlightLeg` is, for example, requiring 100 bytes, it would need 60,000,000 bytes of memory, which is huge, especially when contiguous memory is to be allocated.
- After multiple allocations of this huge size, the memory available to your process will be limited. You may need to compile and build a 64-bit version of the same, so that you can utilize more (much more) memory.
- Allocation of this size, and this type is not recommended. You should use some collection class (like `vector`, `list`) for the same. Even if array size is constant, I would not recommend compile time allocation (i.e, stack allocation).

Comment: Thanks Ajay. I have to store that much of data in memory in order to reduce the disk access time. actually one FlightLeg is 200 bytes. I have 8GB RAM. I'll try vector.

Comment: 1. RAM size doesn't mean you can access it all. If it is 32-bit process, you cannot access more than 2GB. You need to have a 64-bit process to have/access more memory.
2. Even if you store (such huge stuff) in memory, OS may page-out some memory into disk. AND, even if you read from disk, OS may cache and/or optimize the file-reading for you. 
Use vector!